# Don't understand why changing pointer of one variable affects the variable it's copied from

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have this piece of code that helps me to sort a linked list whose nodes contain a singular word. From my understanding of insertion sort, I've managed to come up with this which works fine, but there is a part where I've copied from online and need help in understanding it.

```
Node* insertion_sort(Node* head) {
    Node* dummy;
    dummy= malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (dummy == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation error");
    }
    dummy->next = head;
    Node* last_sorted = head;
    Node* current = head->next;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if(strcmp(last_sorted, current) <= 0) {
        last_sorted = current;
        }
        else {
            Node* prev = dummy;
            while (strcmp(prev->next->word, current) < 0) {
                prev = prev->next;
            }
            last_sorted->next = current->next;
            current->next = prev->next;
            prev->next = current;
        }
        current = last_sorted->next;
    }
    return dummy->next;
}
```

In the line

```
prev->next = current;
```

Why would it also change the value of where my dummy node points to? Wouldn't the 2 nodes be independent of one another? I suspect this is due to how pointers work as this is very new territory for me.

I have tried running through the debugger and saw the changes but I do not understand why/how does this occur.

Comment: draw it on paper. It will help you uinderstand

Comment: `if (dummy == NULL) { printf("Memory allocation error");} dummy->next = head;` contains at least 2 major mistakes.  Error messages belong on stderr, and "Memory allocation error" sure feels like an error message.  The newline is missing as well.  It ought to be either `fputs("Memory allocation error\n", stderr)` or `perror("malloc");`.  More importantly, you can't just print the error message and continue.  You have detected that `dummy` is NULL, so you cannot then reference  `dummy->next`!  You need to return (or exit).

Comment: Unrelated to the main problem, note that the code `dummy= malloc(sizeof(Node)); if (dummy == NULL) { printf("Memory allocation error"); } dummy->next = head;` is dangerous.  The error should be reported to `stderr`, not `stdout`, but (much more significantly), the chances are that the error message will be followed immediately by a crash as your code dereferences the null pointer in `dummy`.  You need to abandon the function if the memory allocation fails.  You also allocate the memory but never free it; this is not a good idea (it's a memory leak).

Comment: @WilliamPursell: were you copying my screen as I typed?  You have a good point about the newline for the error message; I think I have a good point about the memory leakage.

Comment: @tthh The function in whole is wrong and can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the clarification there. However, in this case, in my task allocated I was told to print a line stating "Memory allocation error" and continue on with the project. I do see what's the problem now if there's an actual error. 
@JonathanLeffler, in my main function after I have printed out my linked list, I would then free it, is this an acceptable behavior or must I free in the same scope?

Comment: I've not tracked all the memory usage, but usually a sort does not add elements to what is sorted.  You allocate the dummy node; you don't free it.  I'm not clear whether it's linked into the list (if so, what value is stored in it?), but I'd assume it was effectively a temporary element.  You should probably free it before the function returns.

Comment: I understand that this is a `c` question and that it's an assigned task. Using [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) is recommended if `c++` is an option - instead of writing your own linked list implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dummy` is a pointer to a node - it's not a node. `prev` is a pointer to a node - it's not a node.

The nodes are created by `malloc` and they don't have names. That's why it's important to keep track of which pointers are pointing to what.

If you do:

```
Node* dummy = malloc(sizeof(Node));
Node* prev = dummy;
prev->word = "hello";
```

then the node's `word` is `"hello"`, and both `prev` and `dummy` point to the node, so `dummy->word` is also `"hello"`. `prev->word` and `dummy->word` are the exact same variable.

If this is still too confusing because the node doesn't have a name, you may think about pointers to variables which have names:

```
int i;
int* p = &i;
int* q = &i;
```

both `*p` and `*q` and `i` are the same variable. `p` isn't `q`, but `*p` is `i` and `*p` is also `i`, so `*p` is `*q`.

If you do `*p = 42;` then `*q` is also 42 because both of them are `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The pointers are pointing to the exact same object, not copies of the object. You can confirm this by looking at the contents of the `prev` and `dummy` variables - they will have the same value. When performing the assignment, it's changing the single object that both of the variables are pointing to.